# Regexp constraint rejecting apparently valid data in Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, constraints

Using Postgres 10.3 with pgAdmin 4 v3.0

I have a constraint for GB national grid references on a column **gridref** of a table **my_table**:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_gridref_check 
CHECK (gridref::text 
~~ '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text);
```

I have a grid reference which appears to match that format (AB12345678 - ie 2 alpha, 8 numeric - not a real grid reference, but a valid pattern), but on trying to insert a record with that value, the insert fails on that constraint, with this error

```
ERROR: new row for relation "my_table" violates check constraint "my_table_gridref_check"
```

However, if I do

```
SELECT select regexp_matches('AB12345678',
'[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

then I get as a result the single-item set containing that grid ref.

All of which seems to indicate that the grid ref *should* be accepted (which is what I expected), so I don't understand why the constraint is triggering.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Are there restrictions or gotchas on the use of regular expressions as constraints in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look this up in the documentation:

> The operator ~~ is equivalent to LIKE, and ~~* corresponds to ILIKE.

Postgres does not support character ranges in `LIKE`.

You want `~` (or `regexp_match()`):

```
CHECK (gridref::text ~ '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text);
```

I'm guessing you really want:

```
CHECK (gridref::text ~ '^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'::text);
```

Note the anchors so this matches the entire string.

Or more simply:

```
CHECK (gridref::text ~ '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$'::text);
```

Comment: Fabulous, that's exactly what I needed. The constraint was translated by pgAdmin into pg format, so I didn't catch the nuance between "~" and "~~". Many thinks